# Cannot reuse custom StoryboardSegue class for multiple segues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to create custom animation for segues between multiple view controllers for new users to set up their app in steps. I'm trying to use the same custom UIStoryBoardSegue class (where I override perform func) for all segues since it seems inefficient to create one for each when they're all the same animation.

The following works the first time but then doesn't even hit the breakpoint when I use the same UIStoryBoardSegue class again later.

```
override func perform() {
    let firstVCView = source.view!
    let secondVCView = destination.view!

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: screenWidth, dy: 0.0)

    let superView = firstVCView.superview
    superView?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = firstVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
        secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        self.source.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Any idea what's missing, or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer your question. At the end of your animation, you have forgotten established a relationship between source and destination controllers. In other words, you have to manually present your destination.

If you don't want to remove your source view controller from the vc stack, just don't dismiss your source view controller and add self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil), like the following.

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.frame = firstVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
        secondVCView.frame = secondVCView.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0.0)
    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
           self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
      //  self.source.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    })
```

If you want to dismiss, you have to use parent vc of your source vc to push or present destination vc, like UINavigationViewContoller or UITabViewController. Hope this solve your questions.